# Getting error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: when running feature file

Tags: cucumber

When I am running my feature file i am getting the below error:-

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must exist: C:\Users\bajaj\eclipse-workspace\cucumberpractices\src\test\java\AppFeatures\Search.Feature

Please find attached screenshot of feature file and step definition file

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should post your cucumber runner file? Also, post code and not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Error came because it was taking incorrect feature file